# Python Flask html form not displaying - GET instead of POST method?

Tags: python, html, authentication, flask, forms

I'm trying to learn python and some of the Python web frameworks. Currently I'm following following a Flask course, but have run into a problem with an html form that I cannot find a solution to.

The code below is supposed to create a very simple page at '/' where the user can log in using an html form and is redirected to /main upon successful login.

However instead of display the html form, the page immediately redirects to /main.

At least part of the problem seems to be that `request.method` is returning `GET`, rather than `POST`, since when I add `flash(request.method)`, `GET` is returned.

I've checked the code multiple times and it is exactly the same as the tutorial I'm following, but the result is not the same.

I'm using python 3.5 and I believe Flask version 0.10.1.

This is my main python file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, \
flash, redirect, url_for, g
import sqlite3

# configuration
DATABASE = 'blog.db'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'admin'
SECRET_KEY = 'hard_to_guess'

app = Flask(__name__)

# pulls in app configuration by looking for UPPERCASE variables
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# function used for connecting to the database
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME'] or\
        request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/main')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the `login.html` code:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Welcome to the Flask Blog!</h2>
    <h3>Please login to access your blog.</h3>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your indentation levels are off of the `if ...then ...else` block in your `request.method == 'POST'` logic.  Indent your `else` block to match up and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was the problem. I had been looking for that for hours, but had aligned the else with the wrong if.